# Getting the next Entry with Date

Tags: mysql, date

I don't know how to explain exactly, but I will try it:

I have a Table in my MySQL Database which has a Date-Row.The Date is formatted as `DD-MM`.

I need a Query which gives me the next possibly Entry from the current Date on.

I Hope, somebody understand...

Comment: You can't store *only* DD-MM in a DATETIME column so can we assume that the columntype is VARCHAR?

Comment: Post some sample data and desired o/p. That will be crystal clear for all the viewers instead of your explanation.

Comment: Yes it is. The Query is sent by C#.

Comment: What kind of sample data you want to see? I don't know what i could Post..

Comment: There is no way to determine next possible date for `28-02` without a year.

Comment: @Styler2go - Suppose you have `28-03`, `29-03`, `01-06` and `05-08`. What should the query return?

Comment: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EObw2.png)
Here is an Example / Sample Image...

Comment: So *what* should the query return?

Comment: The nearest Entry in "wann" Column to the current Date...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports Date Comparisons so if you have a date you can do:

```
Select * FROM TABLE WHERE TIMEFIELD > "2012-03-29 14:33:32";
```

In that case the string is hard-coded, I'm not sure if that's what you want exactly since it's a bit vague, but you can adapt it.

Comment: I think this won't work with VARCHAR and a Custom Date-Format?

Comment: Because the Data comes from an IRC where it is more Comfortable to just Type in DD-MM fast...

Comment: So why don't you parse it into a proper format before storing it in the database?

Comment: Then, the most time, i would convert this Date.. Is there no Way to do that this way? Maybe in C#? So, its just a bit of laziness..